# Как сделать чтобы текст ишел плавно вместе с dropdown-menu?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
let p = document.querySelector('p')
button.onclick = function() {
  p.classList.toggle('transform');
  p.classList.toggle('untransform-menu');
};
```

```css
.strip{
 background: #444 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 32px;
}

.strip:first-child{
 margin-top: 0px !important;
}

.btn-strip{
 border: 1px solid black !important;
 border-radius: 0px !important;
 padding: 10px !important;
}

p{
 transition: transform 0.3s linear; 
}

.transform{
 transform: translateY(-150px);
}

.untransform-menu{
 transform: translateY(150px);
}


@keyframes down1 {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  10% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  25% {
    height: 25px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  75% {
    height: 75px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 80px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100px;
  }
}

.btn-strip:focus ~ .dropdown-menu {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation-name: down1;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->  
<!-- Кнопки, объединенные в группу с помощью класса .btn-group -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-strip">
      <span class="strip"></span>
      <span class="strip"></span>
      <span class="strip"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Выпадающее меню -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <!-- Пункты меню -->
      <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
 <p>dasdgkajlsk;dl'as;ldkfahsgajkl;skkdfjask</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.btn-strip:focus ~ .dropdown-menu {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation-name: down1;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Все просто - **overflow: hidden;**